# Caption, the label and the numbering bold, meanwhile the text is not bold. How to fix the text size?

Tags: ms-word

In Word I have made a caption (Figure 1,2,3) and I want to make the label and the numbering bold, meanwhile the text is not bold.

Example:
**Figure 1.** Text.

I found the macron below fixing this, however, the label and numbering has the size 12, meanwhile the text is 10. I want to control the text size (they should be the same). Does anyone know how to fix this? What would the code be?

Thanks!

```
Sub caption_bold_not()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngCap As Range
With ActiveDocument
  On Error Resume Next
  .Styles.Add "CaptionLabel", wdStyleTypeCharacter
  On Error GoTo 0
  .Styles("CaptionLabel").Font.Bold = True
  .Styles("Caption").Font.Bold = False
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = ""
      .Style = "Caption"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = True
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      Set RngCap = .Words.First
      With RngCap
        .MoveEnd wdWord, 1
        .Style = "CaptionLabel"
      End With
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the font.size property:

```vb
  With .Styles("CaptionLabel").Font
    .Bold = True
    .Size = 10
  End With
```

Furthermore - in case you have to build an international solution - you should reference the built-in styles by their constant names as the local names are translated (in German e.g. the style is called "Beschriftung" instead of "Caption")

`.Styles(wdStyleCaption).Font.Bold = False`

and

`.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleCaption).NameLocal`